# Import table with all primary key and foreign key from oracle to SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, import, oracle11g

I try  to import some tables from My oracle SGBD to SQL Server 2008. But I am facing many trouble.
When I  import using import/export wizard options, I am able to import all my table with data, but without any relation between  my tables, the Foreign keys and primary key are not exported.

How can I import all my table with a different relation(foreing keys and primary key) between us??
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "SGBD" stand for?  What application are you using that has an "import/export wizard"?  There are quite a few tools that you might be using.

Comment: Oracle 11G is the SGBD that I stand for, The tools I use is on: programs>Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2>Import and Export data(32 bits). Also the same option can be access by right click on database target in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: I'm still not sure what "SGBD" stands for.  I'm assuming you're talking about an Oracle database.  Do you mean "RDBMS"?  Do you need to use this tool?

Comment: Yes I am talking about Oracle Database, I don't know If I need this tool ,but I found the steps to do that on Internet. I just want to migrate the table from  my oracle database to SQL server with the relation(primary and foreing key) between all my table. But I don't really know how. If you have another solution you can suggest to me.